# How to set required Edit fields with a red border?

Tags: delphi

I want to require a little fields. And when they will not be filled in that they will be red and needed to fill in.
before the post can be done

Here is a screenshot of what do I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing that story. What is your question?

Comment: the question is how to mark that those fields are required

Comment: You can mark them however you want. You suggested using a colored border, which is fine. Other programs put an asterisk next to the field. Others highlight the label somehow. Others make the control a different color. Do whatever you want.

Comment: Ok thanks, but can you tell me how to do this in delphi. I already know how to do it in other programmas but delphi is new to me

Comment: So describe or show the image of how do you want that field to be highlighted.

Comment: http://imgur.com/pFaICsZ I want it highlighted when its not filled in like on this pic.

Comment: Simplest way of doing what you want would be to handle `TEdit.OnChange()` event, check in that event if value of `TEdit` is empty and color it red, otherwise give it `clWindow` colour.

Comment: You made it to work? No problem, glad I helped.

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic Yeah made it work

Comment: I would simply write `Edit1.Color := clRed`

Comment: Put edits onto TPanel and change that panel's background .Color to red or to nutral gray as you see fit. I also suggest you run Validators demo from JediVCL library, it seems close to  your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add a `TShape`, which can draw a red line around your edit box. If you want the red border to replace the normal TEdit border you can modify the properties of your Edit control so it has no Border.

If you want the shape to be unfilled, change brush style to `bsClear`

Comment: Is it possible to draw an unfilled rect with a Shape? I mean, I thought one could paint filled rectangles with Shapes.

Comment: @Erik Yes, use the `Pen` property, and set `Brush.Style = bsClear`. But that wouldn't be necessary here: a Shape is a TGraphicControl and will always stay behind the Edit control thus showing no interior.

Answer (score 5):

You might hook the WM_Paint message and draw a rectangle on the ControlCanvas if required. One way to do this could look like this:

```
unit Edit_WithFrame_If_Needed_But_Empty;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TEdit = Class(StdCtrls.TEdit)
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
    procedure WMKEYUP(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_KEYUP;
  private
    FPaintedRed: Boolean;
    FRequired: Boolean;
    procedure CheckForInvalidate;
  published
  public
    Property Required: Boolean read FRequired Write FRequired;
  End;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TEdit }
procedure TEdit.CheckForInvalidate;
begin
  if Required and (Length(Trim(Text)) = 0) then
  begin
    if not FPaintedRed then
      Invalidate;
  end
  else if FPaintedRed then
    Invalidate;
end;

procedure TEdit.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  CheckForInvalidate;
end;

procedure TEdit.WMKEYUP(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  CheckForInvalidate;
end;

procedure TEdit.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  CC: TControlCanvas;
begin
  inherited;
  if Required and (Length(Trim(Text)) = 0) then
  begin
    FPaintedRed := true;
    CC := TControlCanvas.Create;
    try
      CC.Control := Self;
      CC.Pen.Color := clRed;
      CC.Pen.Width := 3;
      CC.Rectangle(ClientRect);
    finally
      CC.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
    FPaintedRed := false;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Required := true;
  Edit3.Required := true;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I would like to implement the same using DBEdit. @bummi: Could you please tell me how Is it possible using DBEdit?

Comment: @kirankumar just declare *TDBEdit = Class(VCL.DBCtrls.TDBEdit)* instead of  *TEdit = Class(StdCtrls.TEdit)*, same for implementation, e.g. *procedure TDBEdit.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);* , the code stays the same.

Comment: Thanks it worked using DBEdit. But if i use the same logic with TDBComobobox = Class(VCL.DBCtrls.TDBCombobox), it throws an error saying unrecognizable field 'Required'.