# How to set DBCombobox fields with a red border to show to user as a mandatory field?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Similar to the question which has been posted 
[How to set required Edit fields with a red border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813982/how-to-set-required-edit-fields-with-a-red-border#) answered by Mr. Bummi

I would like to know, is it possible for using the same implementation for DBCombobox or not?

Comment: Yes, for the accepted answer. It doesn't really depend on the type of component having a red box around it.

Comment: But it's mentioned that it throws an error saying 'unrecognizable field Required' when used for DBcombobox

Comment: *"But it's mentioned that it throws an error saying..."* - Why wont you try it yourself?

Comment: @kobik: I have tried using the same code stated and I am also getting the same error

Comment: You are probably not using the code correctly. Since it uses an interposer class, the unit (if you use one) must be the last in the uses clause (**after** `VCL.DBCtrls`). Or derive a new descendant class from `TDBCombobox` and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following (it is verified on Delphi 10 Seattle).

```
  TDBCombobox = Class(VCL.DBCtrls.TDBCombobox)
  private
    FBordercolor: TColor;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure SetBorderColor(AColor: TColor);
  published
    property BorderColor: TColor read FBorderColor write SetBorderColor default clBlack;
  end;


    ....
    
Implementation

procedure TDBCombobox.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  inherited;
  Self.Canvas.Pen.Color := FBorderColor;
  Self.Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  Self.Canvas.Polyline([Point(0, 0), Point(Width-1, 0), Point(Width - 1, Height - 1),
                        Point(0, Height - 1),Point(0, 0)]);
end;

procedure TDBCombobox.SetBorderColor(AColor: TColor);
begin
  FBorderColor := AColor;
  invalidate;
end;
```

It is the same idea like the post you linked, You use a hack to add features to standard components.

If it is worth it, then you should create a descendant like @kobik said.

**If a standard component needs a new feature, then it is not a standard any more.**